# How to add multiple rows to bottom app bar

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bottomappbar

Can I modify bottomappbar in flutter to look like this or should I use container to have multiple buttons like this..

[image]

I've tried it using bootomappbar But I don't know how to have multiple rows.

```
BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                }
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Use One Column and inside This Column add Two Rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Column` with Multiple `Rows`

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Container(
      height: 150,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {}),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ]),
          Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {}),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ]),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```